# Django: print latest download date and how many new entry since last download

Tags: python, django

In my app I've created a working function to dowload all the user information in my database. In my html page I'd like also to add the date of the latest time that the csv file was downloaded and how many new profile where added since the last download. I've thought to use the iformation stored in the name file to do so but I'm getting this error name  `'file_name' is not defined`

account.views

```
@login_required
def download_csv(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    profile_total = Information.objects.all().count()
    profile_csv_date_donwload = str(datetime.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
    file_naname = + profile_csv_date_donwload + str(profile_total) +'.csv'
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + file_naname     
    
    writer = csv.writer(response, delimiter=';')

    info = Information.objects.all()

    writer.writerow(['first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'birthdate'])

    for i in info:
        writer.writerow([i.first_name, i.last_name, i.gender, i.birthdate])

    return response
```

donwload.views

```
from account.views import download_csv
def download_page(request):
    profile_total = Information.objects.all().count()
    latest_d_csv = file_name[0:10] 
    latest_n_csv = file_name[11:] 
        new_profile = profile_total - int(latest_n_csv)
    context = {
               'profile_total': profile_total,
               'latest_d_csv': latest_d_csv
               'latest_n_csv': latest_n_csv
               'new_profile': new_profile

               }
    return render(request, 'page/download.html', context)
```

html

```
            <div class="col-md-8">      
              <div class="row gutters-sm">  
                <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
                  <div class="card h-100">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h6 class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3">Profile CSV</h6>    
                       <br/>                      
                           <small>Profile in Database: {{ profile_total }}</small>
                           <br/>                       
                           <small>Latest Download: {{ latest_d_csv}}</small>
                           <br/>  
                           <small>New Profile: {{ new_profile }}</small>                                              
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

File_name in download_page is not defined, so either to call this function from download_cv where file_name is defined and passing file name as an argument,  or passe it via redirect download_cv to download_page..

Check if there is typo error in below line( its file_naname instead of file_name)
file_naname = + profile_csv_date_donwload + str(profile_total) +'.csv

How to pass argument to view function:

1-passing argument from function to function (both function take request as an argument):

in url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('lowad_page/<str:file_name>', view.downlowad_page, name='downlowad_page'),
]
```

in view.py

```
def download_csv(request):
     .
     .
     .
return redirect('downlowad_page', file_name)

def download_page(request, file_name):
      .
      .
      .

return response(request, ......)
```

2-In html you can pass the argument by using url tag:
`"{% url 'downlowad_page' file_name %}"` make sure file name is passed to html (you can pass it via context)

Comment: Thank you! Could you help me with some example on how to achieve what you are you saiying? Thank again

Comment: I have added 2 examples, if you find my answer useful then please upvote my answer, thanks in advance